# How to create advanced splines in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I am a designer/typographer that recently started in the world of programming. I am very excited about threeJS and all the possibilities to create great interactive stuff with it.

I want to create a custom spline and extrude a shape on it, like this example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1f47i3tmq5icz2/Screenshot%202014-07-06%2020.03.50.png

I've seen that I need to draw the ThreeJS vectors:

```
    var sampleClosedSpline = new THREE.ClosedSplineCurve3([
        new THREE.Vector3(0, -40, -40),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 40, -40),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 140, -40),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 40, 40),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, -40, 40),
    ]);
```

It is a tool to simplify the process? Or I have to make every point by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out and I want to share it with everybody.

There is a plugin for illustrator named AI2Canvas

after you simplify your design into straight lines (no bezier curves) you can export it and it will give you points like these ones:

```
  ctx.lineTo(36.4, 96.4);
  ctx.lineTo(44.0, 84.6);
  ctx.lineTo(44.7, 76.4);
  ctx.lineTo(44.7, 66.5);
  ctx.lineTo(44.7, 46.5);
  ctx.lineTo(44.9, 33.0);
  ctx.lineTo(48.9, 21.6);
  ctx.lineTo(60.8, 14.6);
  ctx.lineTo(75.0, 17.3);
  ctx.lineTo(83.3, 30.4);
```

Then by your wisdom of your editor you can make them like these ThreeJS friendly:

```
 new THREE.Vector3(12.2- 100, 98.9),
  new THREE.Vector3(36.4- 100, 96.4),
  new THREE.Vector3(44.0- 100, 84.6),
  new THREE.Vector3(44.7- 100, 76.4),
  new THREE.Vector3(44.7- 100, 66.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(44.7- 100, 46.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(44.9- 100, 33.0),
  new THREE.Vector3(48.9- 100, 21.6),
  new THREE.Vector3(60.8- 100, 14.6),
  new THREE.Vector3(75.0- 100, 17.3),
  new THREE.Vector3(83.3- 100, 30.4),
```

There is no Z axis on these ones, luckily we can have only XY to define a point